Dividing an inverse of a matrix by its determinant after row reduction
I understand that A inverse = 1/det(A) * adj(A). Usually when I find A  inverse, I use the row reduction method, which involves putting the identity matrix on the right, and reducing A on the left to become the identity matrix and then you have A inverse on the right. When I was doing my homework, I realized that they divided the inverse by det(A), but when I use the row reduction method, I only get A inverse without the scaling factor - does this mean that every time I use row reduction method to find the inverse of a matrix, I must divide by det(A) as well?
Edit: Basically I'm not really sure as to where the 1/5 came from, as using row reduction (https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-inverse-row-operations-gauss-jordan.html) i only get the matrix without the scalar 1/5.



Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Perhaps you should edit your post to show us an example so we can see what's going wrong

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The formula means that if you have computed the adjoint and you want to calculate the inverse, you have to divide the entries of the adjoint by the determinant.

edited, hope it is clearer now

yes, now I can answer your question

You must be calculating the determinant wrong.
$\det\pmatrix{1&1&0\\-1&-2&1\\0&1&-2}=1$, not $5$.
Perhaps you miscalculated it as $1\det\pmatrix{-2&1\\1&-2}+1\det\pmatrix{-1&1\\0&-2}$ instead of
the correct $1\det\pmatrix{-2&1\\1&-2}\color{red}-1\det\pmatrix{-1&1\\0&-2}$.
Bottom line:  you should get the correct answer with row reduction,
without need to divide by the determinant.
